# Как установить фиксированное фоновое изображение для всех страниц?

Tags: java, .net, pdf, sdk, itext

По нажатию кнопки мы создаем 4 страницы в PDF. Мы добавили фоновое изображение:

```js
string imageFilePath = parent + "/Images/bg_image.jpg";
iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageFilePath);
jpg.ScaleToFit(1700, 1000);
jpg.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING;
jpg.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
document.Add(jpg);
```

Изображение добавляется только к первой странице, но если я создаю PDF-файл с большим количеством содержимого и несколькими страницами, то изображение `bg` появляется только на последней странице. Я хочу, чтобы фоновое изображение отображалось на всех страницах.

Answer (score 0):

Фон добавляется только один раз, потому что вы добавляете его один раз.
Если вы хотите добавлять содержимое к каждой странице, то это нужно делать не вручную, потому что неизвестно, когда в iText будет созданановая страница. Вместо этого следует использовать обработчик событий.
В iText 7 можно использовать интерфейс `IEventHandler` и переопределить метод `handleEvent()`:

```js
public class BackgroundEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
    protected Image img;
 
    public BackgroundEventHandler(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
    }
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
 
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.getDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamBefore(),
                page.getResources(), pdfDoc);
        Rectangle area = page.getPageSize();
        new Canvas(canvas, pdfDoc, area)
                .add(img);
    }
}
```

Теперь фоновое изображение будет добавляться прямо к содержимому во время создания каждой страницы. Мы используем `PdfCanvas` и метод `newContentStreamBefore()` для получения потока содержимого под содержимым страницы.
Теперь мы создаем пример этого события и применяем его для события `PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE`:

```js
BackgroundEventHandler handler = new BackgroundEventHandler(img);
pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, handler);
```

Объект изображения определяется следующим образом:

```js
Image img = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(imgSrc))
            .scaleToFit(1700, 1000)
            .setFixedPosition(0, 0);
```

Обратите внимание, что 1700 на 1000 — это достаточно большой размер. Вы уверены, что это правильные размеры для вашей страницы?